# Homework: Second derivative of $\langle Ax, x \rangle$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, inner-products

So let $A \in M_{n}$ and define $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \langle Ax, x \rangle $. Find f' and f''.

After some work, I found the first derivative to be $f'(x)(v) = \langle Ax, v \rangle + \langle Av, x \rangle = \langle (A^T + A)x, v \rangle$.

That is not what I'm having trouble with.

I don't think it is necessary to compute the second derivative the "long way" through a complicated limit.

I believe that since $f'$ is itself a linear function, then we should have $f''(x) = f'$. That $f''(x)(v,w) = f'(v,w) = \langle (A^T + A) v, w \rangle$.

However I don't know how to justify this. I feel that there are some basic mechanics that I am missing. I am more interested in the mechanics than in a direct answer.

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP is looking for calculus-type differentiation rules for multivariable functions, especially in terms of differentiating inner products, finding second derivatives, etc.

Comment: You are right: since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Hilbert space, the derivative can be identified to a vector (the gradient). You have proved that $\nabla f(x)= \left(A^T+A \right)x$. This map is linear in $x$, therefore its derivative is represented by the matrix $\left(A^T+A \right)$. Can you write down $\nabla f(x+w)$ explicitly?